# authlogic email as username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

How do i override/set authlogic to use the email field instead of the username field for both signup and authentication, having a username + an email is occasionally too intense for some some registration scenarios

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you simply remove the `login` column and add an `email` column, authlogic will do the rest.

See this example [readme](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example/blob/master/README.rdoc) for all the optional/required DB columns.

Comment: magic!. Also i found using this also worked:

  acts_as_authentic do |c|

        c.login_field = :email

  end

Comment: I needed to login with email, yet retail the username. So I prefer ADAM's comment answer.

Answer (score 11):

better answer try this... well, update authlogic gem if needed!

user_session.rb

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  find_by_login_method :find_by_email #for example or you can make what ever method see exapmle 2
end
```

--- **example 2**

user_session.rb

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  find_by_login_method :find_by_anything
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic

  def self.find_by_anything(login)
    find_by_login(login) || find_by_email(login) || find_by_id(login)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

As Adam's comment contains a good answer to this question. Add this to your user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic do |c| c.login_field = :email end
end
```